# How do I call an instance variable that is inside a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, instance-variables

I want to call an instance variable that uses an equation. I need "i" from the for loop to calculate the total price. My variable bonePrice does not work inside the for loop or outside.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < stalls.size(); i++){
        if (stalls.get(i).speak().equals("MOO")){
            while (stalls.get(i).isStillHungry() == false)  {
                stalls.get(i).feed(FoodType.GRASS);
                stalls.get(i).isStillHungry();
                }
            System.out.println("Stall " + (i+1) + " of " + stalls.size() + " contains a cow who had " + stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings + " feedings, which cost " + df.format(grassCost * stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings));

        }

    if (stalls.get(i).speak().equals("WOOF")){
        while (stalls.get(i).isStillHungry() == false)  {
            stalls.get(i).feed(FoodType.BONE);
            stalls.get(i).isStillHungry();
            }
        System.out.println("Stall " + (i+1) + " of " + stalls.size() + " contains a dog who had " + stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings + " feedings, which cost " + df.format(boneCost* stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings));

        }

    if (stalls.get(i).speak().equals("MEOW")){
        while (stalls.get(i).isStillHungry() == false)  {
            stalls.get(i).feed(FoodType.SALMON);    
            stalls.get(i).isStillHungry();
            }
        System.out.println("Stall " + (i+1) + " of " + stalls.size() + " contains a cat who had " + stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings + " feedings, which cost " + df.format(salmonCost* stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings));

         double bonePrice = boneCost* stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings;
         double grassPrice = grassCost* stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings;
         double salmonPrice = salmonCost* stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings;
                }


    }       

    System.out.println("Old MacDonald's total expenses: ");
    System.out.println("$5.00 spent feeding 1 cow(s) 5 total feedings"
                        + "\n$25.00 spent feeding 1 cat(s) 5 total feedings"
                        + bonePrice +"\nspent feeding 1 dog(s) 5 total feedings" 
                        + "\n\tTotal Cost: " + /*total cost**/);
```

Comment: Not what you asked, but using `==` to compare `String` values is seldom a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be declared outside of the scope of the `for` loop

e.g.

```
double bonePrice = 0.00;

for (int i = 0; i < stalls.size(); i++){

    ..

    bonePrice += boneCost* stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings;
}

System.out.println("$5.00 spent feeding 1 cow(s) 5 total feedings"
                    + "\n$25.00 spent feeding 1 cat(s) 5 total feedings"
                    + bonePrice +"\nspent feeding 1 dog(s) 5 total feedings" 
                    + "\n\tTotal Cost: " + /*total cost**/);
```

Comment: Probably wants to be `+=` not `=` after `bonePrice` in the loop, otherwise you'll just end up with the price from the last iteration, not the total price. And don't get me started on using `double` to store an amount of money.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew what to do but my syntax was off!

Comment: @stetdawg If this solved your problem then you're using a local variable not an instance member. You have your OOP terminology all mixed up there :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say `double bonePrice` you've actually defined a *new* local variable that overshadows any *instance* variable by the same name.

When yo do so within the loop, this *local* `bonePrice` is not visible outside of it. If you move this declaration to outside the loop, it becomes visible throughout the method but still prevents access to the instance variable.

So, to assign the value to the *instance* member, just use it's name like

```
bonePrice = boneCost* stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings;
```

If the `bonePrice` is supposed to keep a running *total* then you probably need to add the costs to it instead of assigning it a new value at every iteration of the loop.

```
bonePrice += boneCost* stalls.get(i).numberOfFeedings;
```

Finally, there are times when you may decide to leave a local variable's name the same as that of an *instance* member (in *constuctor* arguments for example). In such cases, you can remove the ambiguity by making an explicit use of the `this` keyword.

```
this.bonePrice = bonePrice; // instance var = local var here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the instance variable outside where it is declared. If you want to use it just declare it outside the for loop.